# How to refer to a DOM object's state from another DOM object in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a little app that handles products and users. If we have 3 products, then those can be selected and there can be any number of them each. We do this wia MUI Autocomplete element. the counter is a simple TextField of type "number".

A product element looks like this, simplified, with some props and states:

```
type ProductType = {
    key: string,
    label: string
}
```

And the return of the .jsx is like this:

```
[...Array(productLines)].map((e, i) => {  // productLines is 1 by default, but can be added up to the number of the product types, 3 in this example.
    return (
        <Stack direction={"row"} spacing={2}>
            <FormControl>
                <Autocomplete
                    id={"product_" + i}
                    options={labelledProducts} // which are of type ProductType
                    renderOption={(props, option: ProductType) => {
                        return (
                            <li {...props} key={option.key}>
                            {option.label}
                            </li>
                        );
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Product" />}
                    onChange={(event: any, newValue: ProductType | null) => setProduct(event, newValue)}
                    sx={{ width: 400 }}
                />
            </ FormControl>
            <FormControl>
                <TextField 
                id={"count_" + i}
                type="number" 
                InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0 } }} 
                sx={{ width: 120 }} 
                label="Count"
                onChange={(event: any) => setProductCount(event)}/>
            </FormControl>
            <IconButton aria-label="delete" color="error" onClick={() => deleteLine(i)} disabled={i == 0}>  // The first line must remain, as at least one product must be here.
                <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
        </Stack>
        )
    })
}
<IconButton aria-label="addMore" color="primary" onClick={moreLines} disabled={!canAddMoreLines}>
    <AddIcon />
</IconButton>
```

How do I set the final stage showing that these two elements are connected? So How do I save  the count to be related to the product name itself in an object? How would you make the onChange functions? My guess would be to refer to the value of the autocomplete field from the textField, but I don't see how in ReactJs. Please help find a way.